# python visualize 1 RGB pixel

Tags: python, colors, pixel

I have a `RGB` color with the following specifications: `R = 62, B = 120, G = 70`

Is there a way in Python to generate one pixel of this specific `RGB` color in order to be able to see what the color looks like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pixel doesn't seem like it would be visible enough.  How about a small window full of the color?

```
color = (62, 70, 120)
from Tkinter import Tk    # lower case T if you're using Python 3.x
root = Tk()
root['bg'] = "#%02x%02x%02x" % color
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your talking about a console application, that's possible on linux based OS. You would basically instruct the shell to "Add some color", using what's called "ANSI escape sequences", i.e. a special sequence of characters that will be interpreted as coloration.

See: [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)